# Compute only selected components of an eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, eigenvector, numerical-linear-algebra

I am wondering whether it is possible to compute *portions* of the eigenvectors of a given (possibly very big) matrix. More formally, consider the eigenvalue problem $\mathbf{Ax} = \lambda \mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is $n \times n$ Hermitian. For a fixed eigenvector $\mathbf{x}$, I am only interested in the values $\mathbf{x}_k$ for some choices of $k \in \{1,\dots,n\}$.

Is it possible to restrict the computation as above? If not, is it possible to obtain an approximate solution, and under which conditions?

Comment: What is your goal here? What are you trying to achieve that doesn't work with the usual large-scale eigenvalue algorithms?

Comment: You may benefit from "random sampling" of $A$...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. What I'm trying to achieve here is the computation of the heat kernel for a given point of a 2d compact manifold $M$, restricted to the time domain. In particular, given the eigen-decomposition $\Delta_M \phi = \lambda \phi$ of the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta_M$ on $M$, I'm interested in computing the quantity $\sum_{i=1}^m e^{-\lambda_i t} \phi_i(x)^2$ for a given $x\in M$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$. I need to do it very efficiently, that's why I'd like to compute $\phi_i(x)$ instead of the whole $\phi_i$.

Comment: I deleted my prev answer (it didn't answer your question), but I've actually encountered this exact problem before. One can show that the condition you need on $A$ is that it must be well-approximated by a rank-$O(k)$ reduction. I can write out a full answer when I get time.

Comment: Hi Richard. That's very interesting, I'm eager to read your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Here is  some information that you might find useful. The context is that of **PageRank** computation, for the purpose of updating only some of ranks (essentially entries of the eigenvector).

1. Y. Y. Chen, 2004. [Local methods for estimating PageRank values](http://cis.poly.edu/suel/papers/esti.pdf)
2. [Fast incremental and personalized page rank](http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs224w-readings/bahmani10pagerank.pdf)

In general, chasing references for "incremental" pagerank or just "top few ranks" should help you find more related work and ideas.

Alternatively, you could try to solve the problem approximately by using randomization to subsample the matrix $A$, and then using perturbation analysis to estimate the error of approximation --- some ideas for this can be found by following work related to the so-called "CUR" decomposition.

Comment: "Following work" missing.

Comment: :-) --- I mean: "by following the work related to"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointers! I'm going to look into them more in detail and see what I can get out of it.